# Getting all active campaigns in Linkedin

Tags: linkedin-api

I'm trying to get a list of my active campaigns on LinkedIn. I am using the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/ads/account-structure/create-and-manage-campaigns#search-for-campaigns

I copied in the example that documentation, however the elements item is empty. Since this is copied and pasted from the boiler plate example request in the documentation, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

[image: Postman Request]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Permissions issue. Granting access to the Ads API does not mean that you are granted access to campaign data.